# List definitions for a package?

Tags: help, introspection

Is there a way to list definitions for a package? (functions, macros, variables for e.g.).

Once a package is loaded, is there a way to retrieve a list of what it defined?

---

So for example: `(list-symbols-for-package 'subr)` would return a list including `('declare-function 'lambda 'setq-local ...)` and many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs keeps track of where each symbol is defined in [`load-history`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Where-Defined.html#index-load_002dhistory). This is an association list from file paths to the list of symbols defined in each path, with annotations indicating whether the symbol is a variable, a function, etc. The function `file-loadhist-lookup` returns the `load-history` entry for a given file, e.g. `(file-loadhist-lookup "subr")`. This is an internal function of the `loadhist` module, not autoloaded, so you need to `(require 'loadhist)` first.